# What exactly is this question asking? (radix representation of rational numbers)

Tags: irrational-numbers

I'm not asking anyone to solve the problem, I just want to understand it.

[image: Question 1]

At first I thought I just had to change bases, but it seems that I have to do something else (and that's why they've given $M$ and $N$).

The notations $N$, $M$ and $r$ are given below.

[image: Definitions]

Comment: This is the other part: https://i.imgur.com/T6D1JCa.png .

Comment: @MathLover , the question is about "Fixed-Radix Positional Representation of Rational Numbers". From what I've searched, r is the base, N is the number of integers and M is the number of decimal parts.

Comment: I think I understand. If I'm correct in my understanding, then "change base of $x$ to base $r$, then write the numbers $N$ to $M$ of it's representation". E.g. if $x= \pi$ and $N = 2$, $M = -2$, and $r=10$, then answer is $3.14$. See [these notes](http://angom.myweb.cs.uwindsor.ca/teaching/cs265/lec2.pdf) for more of an idea.

Comment: That is the first link that looked correct when i searched "radix representation", so I'm going to venture a guess that you didn't do much searching of your own.